# How to handle nested foriegn keys in django rest

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, django-rest-framework

I am working on an API that has several models, each having a foreign key to its parent. I have figured out how to write the models as well as the serializers file. But I can not figure out how to work around the views file, where I can POST as well as GET data at any level. The tutorials for DRF are quite tricky with only one/two models. Here is my models.py:

```
    class Plant(models.Model):
        plant_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        start_date = models.DateTimeField()
        end_date = models.DateTimeField()
        def __str__(self):
            return(self.plant_name)

    
    class Unit(models.Model):
        plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, related_name='Units', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        unit_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        start_date = models.DateTimeField()
        end_date = models.DateTimeField()
        def __str__(self):
            return(self.unit_name)

    
    class EquipmentCategories(models.Model):
        unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='Categories',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        def __str__(self):
            return(self.category_name)

    
    class Equipment(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(EquipmentCategories,related_name='Equipments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        equipment_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        def __str__(self):
            return(self.equipment_name)
```

I want to write views file such that I can add/view data at any level. Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: Edit: Also, if I add an instance in Unit, I should not have to explicitly add its parent i.e foreign key. Can it be done in backend or is it something frontend handles

Answer (score 0):

Even i was having the similar problem like u , for one level of Forgien key u may obtain it from `__model_name` , but then I shifted to django-smart-selects module in order to obtain chained forgien keys . In your case it would be very simple if u use django-smart-selects

it would be like

```
query = models.ChainedForeignKey(QueryData,**kwargs)
```

Comment: How do I change the views file accordingly? This is specific to the models file

Comment: can u please elaborate it. I am not able to understand

Comment: I mean, I will first have to chain the foreign keys in models.py file, and then do I have to just write this one line of code in views.py that you mentioned?

Edit: I am a complete newbie to this, so pardon me if I am asking silly things

Comment: Also, this will look like dropdowns in the frontend, where I can add any number of instances. For ex . I should be able to add any number of units etc in a particular plant, and I should also be able to add a new plant.
Will this method be useful then? 


Because I dont know how is the data going to come. I just need to know based on the clicking that what has to be the foreign key of the particular unit that I just created is.